# hybridauth (google OAuth integration) and WP problems

Tags: api

I'm trying to implement the script shown here:
 http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/Integrating_HybridAuth_SignIn.html
To allow people to sign in with Google to my site. However I am getting 302 moved, or "`headers already started`" errors. I suspect it has something to do with paths; whereas the hybridauth code is in my theme folder (thats the only way I can include it, or am I wrong?) the callback API can't access /wp-content/themes and so on. Does anyone have any advice on these and what to do?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a plugin I believe? In that case, you can try **[WordPress Social Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-social-login/)** which is based on the [HybridAuth Library](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/) (which you already seem to be using) and [Social Connect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/social-connect/) plugin.

As of now, the plugin supports some 20 services including Facebook, Google, Yahoo, Twitter, Windows Live, Foursquare, Linkedin, and Tumblr, among others.